# I18n Internalization in react for english and hindi

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I am building a single page application using React. I want my website to be available in both the `hindi` and `english` language. So, for that I think I have to use `react-intl`. Okay but how can I make this work? I read a few tutorial but I did not find any good solution for Hindi. Please help me in my research on how to use i18n for English to Hindi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Hindi language uses Devanagari script which is written from left to right (LTR), so translating your site to Hindi isn't different from translating it to any other language (e.g. Frech, Spanish, Czech).

All you need to do is add react-intl components to your code, create a message catalog with messages, translate it into Hindi and load it into your app.

If you have a more specific problem, please update your question or post another one.

---

Also, I'm an author of [lingui](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui) i18n library which you might consider if you're at the beginning of your project. It's successor to react-intl and very similar in usage. There's a [tutorial](https://lingui.js.org/tutorials/react.html), but I could help you with any problems you might have with a Hindi.